# Calling a variable which is a function without passing parameters to it

Tags: javascript, node.js

If you look at this line https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/lib/index.js#L14, you can see that it calls `internals.implementation` without passing in any parameters, but the method has 2 parameters https://github.com/hapijs/hapi-auth-basic/blob/master/lib/index.js#L14.

How does the method `internals.implementation` work if no params are passed into it?

Comment: That line of code isn't calling the function at all. It's passing a reference to the function, presumably to be called later, with parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 14, `internals.implementation` is not actually being called. Rather, a reference to the function is being passed to `plugins.auth.scheme()`, presumably to be invoked later by the `auth` plugin (where actual parameters will be passed).

For example, here's a simplified version:

```js
function sampleImplementation(message) {
    alert(message);
}

function useImplementation(implementation, message) {
    implementation.apply(this, [message]); // invoke the function with args
}

useImplementation(sampleImplementation, "hey there!"); // should alert "hey there!"
```

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. So what if you wanted to add another param to the function. Would you add it as the last param in the method signature so that I don't screw up the first 2 params that get passed in?

Comment: @Catfish You need to define a formal parameter on the function itself at definition-time, and also modify where it's called to supply a third actual argument at call-time. Another option is to pass in a wrapper function instead of `internals.implementation` itself: set `otherArg = "...";` and then define `function(arg1, arg2) { internals.implementation(arg1, arg2, otherArg); }` Pass in the two-argument wrapper function instead of `implementation` itself. (Note this might break things if the consuming function checks explicitly if the callback is `implementation`.)